# Python Image file download with metadata

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write metadata to an image file in Python. I get the image URL from an API and one of the object field has comments which I want to add to my image.

```
response = requests.get(updated_image_url)
download_path = DOWNLOAD_PATH + '/images_test/' + file_name

with open(download_path, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
    f['Comments'] = 'Comments'
```

The above code fails when I try to add comments. However the file is downloaded as expected and saved.

Error for comments:
`TypeError: '_io.BufferedWriter' object does not support item assignment`

I was able to use another snippet to add metdata but that doesn't show the metadata in the comments in Finder. Here is the code:

```
meta = {'Comments': 'my test'}
f.write(json.dumps(meta).encode('utf-8'))
```

Can anyone suggest what I may be doing wrong here and how to save the metadata for the image (jpg) file when I download it? I am using MACOS to run this script.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean you want to set the macOS *"Finder comment"* which pops up when you press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> in the Finder. One way to do that is to shell out from Python to **osascript** to run some **Applescript**.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#
# SetFinderComment.py
# Mark Setchell
#
# Setup: touch junk.txt ~/junk.txt 

import subprocess
import pathlib
import random

def runApplescript(script):
    # Execute some Applescript using "subprocess.run" and "osascript"
    subprocess.run(['osascript', '-e', script], stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)

def setFinderComment(filename, comment):
    # set Finder comment for a file on macOS
    realpath = pathlib.Path(filename).expanduser().resolve()
    script = f'tell application "Finder" to set comment of item POSIX file "{realpath}" to "{comment}"' 
    runApplescript(script)

# Ok, let's test it out, including no path, ~ and making new comment each time it is run
setFinderComment('junk.txt',   f'RANDOM-X: {random.randint(0,65536)}')
setFinderComment('~/junk.txt', f'RANDOM-Y: {random.randint(0,65536)}')
```

The result is this:

[image]

**Note**: You might want to strip any characters that might upset **osascript** - I don't know, I haven't tested, but maybe double quotes, single quotes, slashes?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this library: [exif](https://pypi.org/project/exif/).

It seems pretty straightforward to use:

```
from exif import Image
  with open('grand_canyon.jpg', 'rb') as image_file:
     my_image = Image(image_file)
#To add a new attribute in metadata do
my_image.new_attr = "insert_data_here"
```

There also are some useful methods such as:

- `list_all()` to list all the attributes already present in the
  metadata of the image

Once the metadata is modified as wished, you need to write the new file as such:

```
with open('modified_image.jpg', 'wb') as new_image_file:
     new_image_file.write(my_image.get_file())
```